# Nested MaterialUI Tabs throws an error when opening second tabs level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, tabs, material-ui

I am trying to build a nested horizontal tabs in MaterialUI, I mean, a first tabs level that, when you click on it, open a second tabs level.

Here is a link to the working replicable code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-pasteur-x4m8z?file=/src/App.js

The problem is: When I click on first level, second level is opened, when I click on a item from second level, I get this error

> Material-UI: the value provided to the Tabs component is invalid.
> None of the Tabs' children match with "value21".
> You can provide one of the following values: value11

For replicate the error, you could do next steps:

- Click in "Label 1"
- Click in "Label 1.1"
- Error is thrown

I do not understand why that error, if I am splitting values of each tab in different states and, supposedly, it is all Ok. Maybe the way I use for implementing the nested tab is wrong, any idea what could be happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I created three tab components, one parent and two children. Then I Imported the children tab components into the parent. You can use vertical tabs for the child tab components to help with the layout. check out the how the parent tab looks like. **Note all these are tab components**

```
// Parent tab component
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`full-width-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`full-width-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `full-width-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `full-width-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    width: 500,
  },
}));

export default function FullWidthTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const handleChangeIndex = (index) => {
    setValue(index);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          variant="fullWidth"
          aria-label="full width tabs example"
        >
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <SwipeableViews
        axis={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'x-reverse' : 'x'}
        index={value}
        onChangeIndex={handleChangeIndex}
      >
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0} dir={theme.direction}>
          <ChildTabOne/>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={1} dir={theme.direction}>
          <ChildTabTwo/>
        </TabPanel>
      </SwipeableViews>
    </div>
  );
}
```